# Reflected XSS vulnerability in checkmarx

Tags: apex, visualforce, checkmarx, xss, reflected-xss

The CheckMarx security scanner says that the below line is a Reflected XSS vulnerability.

zip = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('gnfzipcode').escapeHtml4();

The above code is from an Apex class.
I have tried to add escapeHTML4() function at the end in order to fix the vulnerability but still it is not able to fix the issue.

It seems to fix only few of these issues (around 50%).

Please suggest a solution.